# Memory coherency with compute shaders and imageStore

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, shader, compute-shader

I want to use `imageStore` and `imageLoad` in multiple **compute shaders**.

This is mixed with "normal" rendering commands (glDraw) to the screen or to framebuffers, but these don't use `imageStore` or `imageLoad` (only `texture` or `texelFetch`).

I only have one OpenGL context and thread.

My assumptions are the following:

- When doing an `imageStore`, I need to do `glMemoryBarrier` before doing an `imageLoad` in a later compute shader or `texture` or `texelFetch` in a later fragment shader.
- I don't need to use `coherent` at all.
- I don't need to use `glSync` at all.
- I don't need to use `glMemoryBarrier` after writing to a texture using a framebuffer and then reading it with `imageLoad`
- OpenGL will run the compute shaders and "normal" draw operations in the order they are requested. Assuming I use `glMemoryBarrier` between the calls, there are no "threading issues".

**Are they correct?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of those is correct, with the ''possible'' exception of one:

> I don't need to use `coherent` at all.

You may need `coherent`, depending on what your compute shader is doing. If your compute shader writes to an image, then reads from data written by another [invocation within the same dispatch](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Invocation), then you need `coherent`. So if you do an `imageStore`, issue a compute shader `barrier()` call, then do an `imageLoad` to read some other [invocation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Invocation)'s value, then you need the `coherent` qualifier.

`coherent` is about ensuring [visibility within a rendering command](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Internal_visibility) (CS dispatches are considered "rendering commands" in OpenGL). If you don't need internal visibility, then you don't need `coherent`.

---

I want to elaborate on this, because it's a common source of confusion:

> I don't need to use `glMemoryBarrier` after writing to a texture using a framebuffer and then reading it with `imageLoad`

This is absolutely correct. Memory barriers are about ensuring the visibility (and synchronization) of incoherent writes to memory. Rendering to the framebuffer is *not* an incoherent write. So you can use `imageLoad` on such data without needing explicit synchronization.

Assuming of course that you are not [rendering to that framebuffer in the same operation you're `imageLoad`ing from it](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Framebuffer_objects). That rule still applies.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I'm still not entirely sure I understand the `coherent` part: What do you mean by *If your compute shader writes to an image, then reads from data written by another invocation*? What is invocation? You mean another invocation of glDispatchCompute or another invocation of "imageLoad/imageStore"?

Comment: @JanRüegg: I mean a [Shader Invocation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Invocation). With a compute shader, the number of invocations you get is based on the number of workgroups you ask for and the shader's local group size.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So one invocation is basically the processing of one "pixel" or the running of one thread, correct? But I guess, doing this would usually only make sence when using atomic oparations (in addition to the coherent), anyway?

Comment: @JanRüegg: You can have invocations communicate without atomic operations. That's what the `coherent` qualifier and [shader memory barrier functions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Internal_visibility) are for.

Comment: Ok, I think its all clear now, thanks for your patience ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas using coherent in a compute shader, shouldnt use memoryBarrierImage() instead of barrier()? As far as I understand, we're talking about memory coherency, not execution syncronization.

Comment: @user815129: "*shouldnt use memoryBarrierImage() instead of barrier()*" Not in the scenario I outlined, where the intent is to read values written by other CS invocations in the work group. In order to read someone else's writes, those writes must have *happened* first. And only `barrier` ensures execution. `coherent` will ensure visibility of writes that have happened. `memoryBarrierImage` are about the relative order of the writes.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah.. I thougth `coherent` didnt do much by itself (if not paired with a memoryBarrier*) thanks